# php preg_match regex validation always returning false

Tags: php, regex, forms, validation

Bear in mind that with an if statement without the preg_match the validation works but with the preg_match it always returns false

I want to validate the field and make sure it has 8 numbers inside, no more no less.

```
function account_number_validation($validation_result){
  $form = $validation_result["form"];


 if(!preg_match('[0-9]{8}', $_POST['input_19'])){

    // set the form validation to false
    $validation_result["is_valid"] = false;

    //finding Field with ID of 1 and marking it as failed validation
    foreach($form["fields"] as &$field){

        if($field["id"] == "19"){
            $field["failed_validation"] = true;
            $field["validation_message"] = "This field is invalid!";
            break;
        }
    }

}

//Assign modified $form object back to the validation result
$validation_result["form"] = $form;
return $validation_result;
```

}

Any ideas guys?

Answer (score 0):

Change your if statement with:

```
if(!preg_match('/^[0-9]{8}$/', $_POST['input_19'])){
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
// ...
if(!preg_match('#[0-9]{8}#', $_POST['input_19'])) {
// ...
```